# Transplanting part of a multidimensional array to a new array using array_push() in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array called `$results` which looks something like this:

```
[41] => Array
    (
        [id] => 200
        [0] => 200
        [description] => Exercitationem quidem in soluta repellendus. Nihil rem eius doloribus error qui consequatur rerum. Ut ea et reprehenderit ea.
        [1] => Exercitationem quidem in soluta repellendus. Nihil rem eius doloribus error qui consequatur rerum. Ut ea et reprehenderit ea.
        [amount] => 2696.00
        [2] => 2696.00
        [event_class] => 6
        [3] => 6
        [datetime] => 1978-11-19 14:13:20
        [4] => 1978-11-19 14:13:20
    )

[42] => Array
    (
        [id] => 201
        [0] => 201
        [description] => Cupiditate repudiandae aliquid et aut vitae ipsum esse. Odit id debitis atque. Fugiat et dolores tempore officiis.
        [1] => Cupiditate repudiandae aliquid et aut vitae ipsum esse. Odit id debitis atque. Fugiat et dolores tempore officiis.
        [amount] => 23.00
        [2] => 23.00
        [event_class] => 3
        [3] => 3
        [datetime] => 2004-02-23 00:30:56
        [4] => 2004-02-23 00:30:56
    )
```

With the following code, I am trying to extract several consecutive records from a particular part of this array, and move them to a new array called `$fields`. This is for pagination.

```
// based off the desired page, calculate the lowest ID for the record that should be shown
$lower_bound = (int)($_GET['page'] * 10) - 10;

// calculate the highest ID to be shown
$upper_bound = (int)$lower_bound + 10;

$fields = array();
for($i=$lower_bound; $i<=$upper_bound; $i++) {
    $fields = array_push($results[$i]);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($fields);
echo '</pre>';
```

However, `print_r($fields);` returns nothing. Could anyone kindly suggest why this may be?

I am aware that the `array_slice()` function exists, however I need to approach the problem by means of the above.

Comment: Read how [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) works

Comment: Forgo the loop and just use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver, I'd love to. But it needs to be done in this way per the requirements of the project.

Comment: @PatrickQ - I did read the docs before posting. Perhaps you could point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: A project requires a loop and `array_push()`?  Homework project?

Comment: Just use `$fields[] = $results[$i];`

Comment: It's a very small part of a larger assignment. The greater the complexity, the better. Array manipulation is looked upon favourably, and using `array_slice()` wouldn't *really* give me the opportunity to do this. Thank you for your suggestion - it works like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used `array_push()` in forever, and you're not using it properly.  It takes two arguments, an array and the value to push onto the array.  However, just use:

```
for($i=$lower_bound; $i<=$upper_bound; $i++) {
    $fields[] = $results[$i];
}
```

That being said, this is much simpler:

```
$fields = array_slice($results, $lower_bound, 10);
```